# High bill with new instance - What is the correct way of using ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Before I had an instance t2.micro, no problems with billing but I noticed my simulations were slow (I'm using Radiance for image generation and renderings).

So I created a new instance last 30th march (m4.xlarge), added a 100GB volume, created from an AMI so didn't spend much time mounting it, I spent like 4 hours max installing programs then I left it there with no work running. Two days later I received an alert for $8.50 USD already! The detailed billing says 38 hours per on demand Linux hour (my AMI was ubuntu btw) and $0.70 for storage. 
I don't want to think what would be the cost when I start storing data and transferring files.

Perhaps my understanding on how the cost is calculated is wrong, I don't have any work running but the instance is active, should I stop it and activated again every time that I need to use it? but the IP would change and I'd need to be constantly re-configurating it.

Also, I read somewhere advice to terminate the instance after installing the programs and connect to the associated AMI for doing the work. Is that the correct way of using it? I'm using PuTTy so I don't know if it would be the same procedure to connect than when the instance its active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need an instance once in a while, then you definitely want to turn it off when you are not using it to save money. If it is 'running', you are accumulating charges whether or not you are 'using it'.

If you need to keep the ip address the same, then you are going to want to associate an Elastic IP to the instance and that way each time you turn it back on it will have the same IP address. There is a very small charge (like $1/month) for the EIP, so its not free but its very reasonable.

Comment: Ok, I figured it was something like this, thank you so much for your help!